# I have a UITextField in a controller，after text something in it like“a”，I press a UITableviewcell or a button or something else to push a n

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in a controller，after text something in it like“a”，I press a  `UITableviewcell` or a button or something else to push a new controller using

```
   LSIncreaseTypeController *profileViewController = [[LSIncreaseTypeController alloc] initWithShopName:name];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:profileViewController animated:YES];[profileViewController release];
```

then in `profileViewController`,I use

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to back to the first controller ,but here is the question:sometime the `textfeild.text` remain "a" and sometime `textfeild.text=""`,the "a" gone ,I don"t know why?
could someone help me?

Comment: Do you have any code that changes the text field's value?  Where is that code?  What iOS version are you testing with?  After the pop, is the viewDidLoad of the view controller that has the text field getting called again for some reason?  Put a breakpoint or NSLog there to check.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: no code changes the text field's value,andin viewWillDisappear value remains,in viewDidDisappear the value changed to ""

Answer (score 0):

If the text is disappearing that you might want to check to see if the First view is getting released unknowingly.

If the view is released and recreated you will loose the text that was entered into the text field.

Comment: I have't release the firstviewcontroller,and I log the "self" in viewWillDisappear <DFIncreaseSceneController: 0x19acb0f0> ,and the textfeild : <UITextField: 0x19ad17f0; frame = (83 7; 176 32); text = 'T'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x19ad2230>; layer = <CALayer: 0x19ad1a30> in viewDidDisappear:"self":<DFIncreaseSceneController: 0x19acb0f0> textfeild:<UITextField: 0x19ad17f0; frame = (83 7; 176 32); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x19ad2230>; layer = <CALayer: 0x19ad1a30>,the only different id the textfeild.text

Comment: should i add a UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification?

Comment: As the text field is getting empty as the view disappears you should maybe take a closer look at the textfield delegates that you have implemented or the allocation procedure for the text field.Are you adding the textfield programatically ? if so it should be in Viewdidload and not Viewwillappear.

Comment: waho! thank you! that's it,I have't implement the delegate! when I set the  _searchField.delegate = self;all goes well,thank you very mush!